# Powering a Acer netbook using a Lipo battery

Tags: voltage, charger, laptop

Is it possible to power a 10.9v rated Acer Aspire notebook using a 10.9v/3300mah Lipo battery pack via charger port? 
Charger seems to be 19v. Does Notebook really need 19v to work?

I want to use the notebook as the main computer for my robot. Robot uses two 10.9v battery packs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the notebook needs a power source that is higher than battery voltage, to be able to down-convert it and regulate the charge to internal battery. While there are power supply topologies that allow down-convert and up-convert external input source to the desired internal voltage within the same design, these converters are more complicated and more expensive. If your notebook would employ such converter, the input would be specified as having wider range, say, from 9 V to 24 V, which is not the case. So you need a 19V (+-2V I would guess) source to maintain battery functionality in your notebook.

However, since your robot uses batteries with the same voltage as your notebook, you should be able to feed the notebook directly from the robot's batteries, if they don't sag too deep while motion is engaged. You will still need a charger to charge these batteries, likely with the same 19-V source.